# Cannot import function from mysite.views in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

mysite is the app name i created in my django project. below is the hierarchy of my app.

```
mysite
--- views.py
--- tasks.py
--- urls.py
--- __init__.py
```

I have a normal function(there is no request parameter, hence no entry in urls.py as well) in **views.py** as shown below.

```
def function1(param1,param2):
    return something
```

I am trying to import this **function1** in **tasks.py** by using **from .views import function1** but its throwing an error saying **ImportError: cannot import name 'function1' from 'mysite.views'**

Is there any way to get rid of this error.

Comment: It looks all right to me. But how is tasks.py integrated in your project? In your barebone example it won't event attempt the import when you run django. Could you also provide sys.path output?

Comment: @AzamatGalimzhanov i have manually crated tasks.py file...is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the name of the app.

**from [name of app].views import ***

Verify if your app was registered to settings.py